# Python, Vscode: Code snippet in documentation

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, documentation

When we are writing documentation, we usually add some examples of how to use the code.
For example, from pytorch Conv2d function

```
Examples:
        >>> # With square kernels and equal stride
        >>> m = nn.Conv2d(16, 33, 3, stride=2)
        >>> # non-square kernels and unequal stride and with padding
        >>> m = nn.Conv2d(16, 33, (3, 5), stride=(2, 1), padding=(4, 2))
```

Is there a faster way or shortcut to insert `>>>` at the beginning of each line, like ctrl+/ for comment?

Answer (score 0):

Define a key binding

```json
{
  "key": "shift+ctrl+alt+/",  // or other key combo
  "command": "type",
  "args": { "text": "    >>> " },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way I can select multiple lines and use the shortcut? The expected behavior is to add ">>> " at every beginning of the selected line.

Comment: @MuscleGuy with `Ctrl+Alt+ArrowDown` you can add additional cursors, go to line start and apply the keybinding